# I can only see changes to live WP site when logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason I can only see changes to my site when logged in to Wordpress. I've downloaded and modified some files/pages (style.css, content-post.php, etc) using Filezilla but the changes don't appear on any browser without me being logged in to Wordpress. I've tried clearing the cache but no luck. Any idea whats happening, perhaps something to do with temporary files?

Comment: Are you using some caching plugin? (Like W3 Total Cache ? ) Caches would need to be flushed for changes to appear on the blog.

Comment: Yep, as simple as that! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Disable caching plugins if any installed.